# Exit code error with javascript on kata codewars

Tags: javascript

i am trying to solve some kata on code wars , and i got just 1 error in 1 test:undefined , but when i use my code editor to test the output it doesn't get undefined and works perfectly , i may be forgetting something , to compile in the code editor i am using node v12.17.0 and on codewars it is using node v8.1.3 could it be related? here is my code and a link to the kata https://www.codewars.com/kata/514a024011ea4fb54200004b/train/javascript

```
//from what i see the test is 123.net , and when i try it on atom it works normally
//My code

   function domainName(url)
{
  let locate = url.indexOf("/");
  let domain = "";
  let aux;
  if (url.indexOf("http")==-1 && url.indexOf("www")==-1)
  {
    let splitted = url.split(".");
    for(let i=0;i<splitted.length;i++)
    {
      if(splitted[i]!="net" && splitted[i].length>=3)
      {
        return splitted[i];
      }
    }
  }
  else if(url.indexOf("/")!=-1 && url.indexOf("/")<=5)
  {
    for(let i=locate+2;i<url.length;i++)
    {
      domain += url[i];
    }
    let splitted = domain.split(".");
    console.log(splitted);
    for(let i=0;i<splitted.length;i++)
    {
      if(splitted[i]!="www")
      {
        return splitted[i];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    for(let i=locate+2;i<url.length;i++)
    {
      domain += url[i];
    }
    let splitted = domain.split(".");
    console.log(splitted);
    for(let i=0;i<splitted.length;i++)
    {
      if(splitted[i]!="www" && splitted[i].length>3)
      {
        return splitted[i];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "*but when i use my code editor to test the output it doesn't get undefined and works perfectly*" - [it fails for the input `"https://123.net"`](https://jsbin.com/vasepibeye/edit?js,console)

Comment: Also, [here is the same code running on Node](https://repl.it/repls/FrenchUpbeatPlans#index.js). Still doesn't work. The problem seems to be in the code, not CodeWars.

Comment: thanks VLAZ , i fixed the problem was on  if(splitted[i]!="www" && splitted[i].length>3) it just needed >=3